how to create device emulator using command line tools in a docker image
I am trying to setup a bunch of device types to use as emulators in a docker file. However, I have only been able to find and launch the "Nexus 6" device. Ideally I would like to have many devices, like several phones, tablets, android-tvs and automotive type of emulators...
My docker file
FROM openjdk:18-jdk-slim

ARG ARCH="x86_64"   
ARG TARGET="google_apis_playstore"  
ARG API_LEVEL="35" 
ARG BUILD_TOOLS="35.0.0"
ARG ANDROID_API_LEVEL="android-${API_LEVEL}"
ARG ANDROID_APIS="${TARGET};${ARCH}"
ARG EMULATOR_PACKAGE="system-images;${ANDROID_API_LEVEL};${ANDROID_APIS}"
ARG PLATFORM_VERSION="platforms;${ANDROID_API_LEVEL}"
ARG BUILD_TOOL="build-tools;${BUILD_TOOLS}"
ARG ANDROID_CMD="commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip"
ARG ANDROID_SDK_PACKAGES="${EMULATOR_PACKAGE} ${PLATFORM_VERSION} ${BUILD_TOOL} platform-tools emulator"

# ARG EMULATOR_DEVICE="Nexus 6"
# ARG EMULATOR_NAME="nexus"

# ARG EMULATOR_DEVICE="Medium Tablet"
# ARG EMULATOR_DEVICE="Medium Tablet"


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android
ENV PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/${BUILD_TOOLS}"
ENV EMULATOR_NAME=$EMULATOR_NAME
ENV DEVICE_NAME=$EMULATOR_DEVICE

WORKDIR /

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]   
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl sudo wget unzip bzip2 libdrm-dev libxkbcommon-dev libgbm-dev libasound-dev libnss3 libxcursor1 libpulse-dev libxshmfence-dev xauth xvfb x11vnc fluxbox wmctrl libdbus-glib-1-2

# Install required Android CMD-line tools
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/${ANDROID_CMD} -P /tmp \
    && unzip -d $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /tmp/$ANDROID_CMD \
    && mkdir -p $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools \
    && cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools \ 
    && mv NOTICE.txt source.properties bin lib tools/ \
    && cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools \ 
    && ls

# Install required package using SDK manager
RUN yes Y | sdkmanager --licenses  \
    && yes Y | sdkmanager --verbose --no_https ${ANDROID_SDK_PACKAGES}

# Create required emulator
RUN echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "${EMULATOR_NAME}" --device "${EMULATOR_DEVICE}" --package "${EMULATOR_PACKAGE}"



When I try to install a medium tablet, 10 screen size, I get an error :
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# export EMULATOR_DEVICE="Medium Tablet"
root@99031ab5ed4f:/#
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# export EMULATOR_NAME="tab"
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "${EMULATOR_NAME}" --device "${EMULATOR_DEVICE}" --package "${EMULATOR_PACKAGE}"
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
system-images;android-35;google_apis_playstore;x86_64
null


but, when I query the sdkmanager packages, I have serveral to install... but, with a different version of the build-tools...
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# sdkmanager --list --channel=1 | grep -i automotive
  system-images;android-28;android-automotive-playstore;x86                                | 5                 | Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image
  system-images;android-29;android-automotive-playstore;x86                                | 1                 | Automotive with Play Store Intel x86 Atom System Image
  system-images;android-30;android-automotive-playstore;x86_64                             | 2                 | Automotive with Play Store Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
  system-images;android-32;android-automotive-playstore;arm64-v8a                          | 1                 | Automotive with Play Store ARM 64 v8a System Image
  system-images;android-32;android-automotive-playstore;x86_64                             | 1                 | Automotive with Play Store Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
  system-images;android-33;android-automotive;arm64-v8a                                    | 3                 | Android Automotive with Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image
  system-images;android-33;android-automotive;x86_64                                       | 3                 | Android Automotive with Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image


do I have to drop the tool version for each docker image I create to build 32.0.0  so it matches the image type... ?
system-images;android-32;android-automotive-playstore;x86_64
and why are there no tablets available...
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# sdkmanager --list --channel=1 | grep -i tablet
root@99031ab5ed4f:/# sdkmanager --list --channel=1 | grep -i tab
root@99031ab5ed4f:/#

I see there are many examples ( android studio - manually download system image for emulator ) of downloading a package manually, but how do you search dl.google.com to find the available images?
Please advise if there is an easier way to do this... ?
ta,
X
